# Curl or Postman works HTTPClient/Webclient/Restsharp does not for HTTPS POST - missing payload from F5

Tags: curl, post, httpclient, postman, webclient

My goal is to POST to an API over HTTPS through a .NET console app - this being a POC for my final implementation in a web project. Postman, Advanced Rest Client, and cURL works flawlessly, and I am trying to emulate the same request that these clients are making in my console app, and the headers look same, but for some very weird reason the destination - F5 (firewall) does not see the body/payload of the request and comes back saying that there is no payload.

The destination firewall has a rule that checks on my request's - URI and HTTP_Request payload looking for some special keywords. When the same XML is sent through 3rd party clients - Postman, etc. mentioned above, it works but not through my code.

While debugging with the client we have isolated the problem with the payload, their firewall does not see the payload. But if they remove the payload's keyword check, the web service receives the request as expected and returns what it is returning to Postman/others.

If anyone sees anything please feel free to advise. Side note, I have tried TCPClient over sslStream as well with the same results.

Postman headers:

```
content-type: application/xml
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.5
accept: */*
host: destination-for-api.com
content-length: 65
connection: keep-alive
```

My app's headers:

```
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.5
Content-Type: application/xml
Host: destination-for-api.com
Content-Length: 65
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

After over 30 hours of working on this using all that I could think of I am inclined towards the way .NET communicates with the underlying TCP and may be that is why it is not sending the data the way others are. I have also tried using Fiddler/Wireshark and Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 to see the communication, but with Fiddler as soon as that comes in as a proxy the destination does not get payload from any of the 3rd party clients as well.

My code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        var serverName = "https://destination-for-api.com/";
        var webMethod = "add";
        var xmlPostMessage = "<submitRequest><add orderBy='MY_ID'/></submitRequest>";

        //callThruRestsharp(serverName + webMethod, xmlPostMessage);
        //callthruWebClient(serverName + webMethod, xmlPostMessage);
        callThruHttpClient(serverName, webMethod, xmlPostMessage);

        //Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void callThruRestsharp(string server, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient(server);
            client.UserAgent = "PostmanRuntime/7.1.5";

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");

            request.AddParameter("application/xml", message, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static void callthruWebClient(string server, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            String hold = String.Empty;
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/xml");
                client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.1.5");
                client.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");

                hold = client.UploadString(new Uri(server), "POST", message);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(hold);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static void callThruHttpClient(string server, string method, string message)
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(server);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("PostmanRuntime/7.1.5");

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, method);
            request.Content = new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml");

            //var res = client.PostAsync(method, new StringContent(message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")).Result;
            //var res = client.PostAsync(method, new StringContent(message)).Result;
            var res = client.PostAsync(method, request.Content).Result;

            if (res.Content != null)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("THEY SENT: " + Environment.NewLine + res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```